# which select sql is faster?

Tags: sql, postgresql

which sql is faster ? What I am trying to do is find out all fund which have not been snapshoted today. I take snapshot daily and save it in this snapshot table.

```
explain SELECT id from fund where id NOT IN (select id from fund_daily_snap where date_trunc('day',day) = CURRENT_DATE-1); 
                                        QUERY PLAN                                        
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Seq Scan on fund  (cost=76961.83..97431.81 rows=11999 width=4)
  Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on fund_daily_snap  (cost=0.00..76932.96 rows=11550 width=4)
          Filter: (date_trunc('day'::text, day) = (current_date - 1))
OR 



explain SELECT count(id) from fund where id NOT IN (select id from fund_daily_snap where day >= CURRENT_DATE-1); 
                                             QUERY PLAN                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate  (cost=959232109.01..959232109.02 rows=1 width=4)
  ->  Seq Scan on fund  (cost=0.00..959232079.01 rows=11999 width=4)
        Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..78015.88 rows=770033 width=4)
                ->  Seq Scan on fund_daily_snap  (cost=0.00..71157.71 rows=770033 width=4)
                      Filter: (day >= (current_date - 1))
```

Comment: Cannot you compare the `cost` yourself?

Comment: One selects id'd, the other selects count(*), one selects based on  =day, one on >=trunc(day). Which change are you interested in?

Comment: first query doesnt have count(*). Is it mistake?

Comment: You must make use of http://explain.depesz.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you have indeks on "day" column, second solution will become faster by the data increase. Because built-in functions are always have more cost to evaluate.

Comment: Don't have index on day.

Comment: if possible create an index and re-run snapshot.